# CopyFile occurs an error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

In my program there is a picturebox which contains a logo of company. There is a button named 'Change logo'. When button pressed an open file dialog comes and user can choose different picture for logo. Then i want the program to copy the picture to its current directory. I use this code

```
            Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(LogoYolu, My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\Logo\logo.bmp", True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

when i run the program the copyfile code occurs an error "The cannot access the file .... because it is beeing used by another process"
I trying to solve this for about a day! tried to empty the picturebox before copying, or cop the picture to clipbord... and lots of thing but nothing changed. I have searched social.msdn and all over the net but nothing helped. Can you please share your ideas...

Answer (score 0):

What is 'LogoYolu'? CopyFile src and dest parameters are strings, and of course your application needs to be able to access both the source file and destination directory.

Comment: LogoYolu is the string that represents the address of the source.